# AWS Amplify: possible to use Cognito with Lambda authorization?

Tags: authentication, graphql, authorization, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

Amplify allows [specifying multiple authorization strategies](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js/#configure-multiple-authorization-types) on persistence operations. I want to use Lambda authorization for some operations (mutations), and Cognito owner-based authorization for other operations (queries).

In my tests, Cognito conflicts with the Lambda authorization and Lambda execution gets skipped entirely. Is there a way around this?

I read that Lambda authorization [expects a custom auth token to be provided](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/setup-auth-rules/q/platform/js/#configure-custom-authorization-logic-with-aws-lambda). Can I just pass the auth token of the signed-in Cognito user to the Lambda as a "custom" token? The end goal is to have both the Lambda authorizer and the auto-generated VTL resolvers execute.

Comment: Same problem here. any updates ?